# How to retrieve exact label values from a checkbox using django html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

Here is my code for the checkbox. At the moment I retrieve all labels in each of the rows.

```
    <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
<p><label for="id_q">Enter Gene:</label> <input textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" name="q" type="search" value="CYP17A1" /></p>
<p><label for="id_models_0">Disease:</label> <ul id="id_models[]"><td><li><label for="id_models_0"><input checked="checked" id="id_models_0" name="models" input type="checkbox" value="predictgene.amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis_motor_neuron_disease" /> ALT</label></li></td>
<td><li><label for="id_models_1"><input id="id_models_1" name="models[]" input type="checkbox" value="predictgene.arthrogryposis" /> AR</label></li></td>
<td><li><label for="id_models_2"><input id="id_models_2" name="models[]" input type="checkbox" value="predictgene.congenital_myaesthenia" /> CM</label></li></td>
<td><li><label for="id_models_3"><input id="id_models_3" name="models[]" input type="checkbox" value="predictgene.early_onset_dystonia" /> ED</label></li></ul></p></td> 
<br/><br> 
</tr>
<button id="save">Click</button>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Good, you remembered to put HTML now. Only thing remaining is to show what you tried.

Comment: The HTML example is terrible. You can't put `p`, `ul`, `button` just like that into a table row or table. Try at least to break the lines and make it more readable without horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my first time in this platform. Any help on how to post questions will be appreciated.